# Python bind an event from a different file

Tags: python, oop, wxpython

I'm new to python and trying to learn. I am creating a desktop application to record info from a form. I want to create a few panel objects that I will reuse in different frames, and I want to bind an event from the panel object in MyFrame class. I'm not sure if this is possible. Here is my code:

main.py:

```
import wx
from testPanel import testPanel

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def OnClick(self,event):
        print "Clicked"

    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title=title, size=(500,200))
        ...
        myList = ['Project1', 'Project2', 'Project3', 'Project4']
        myPanel = testPanel(self,-1,name="myPanel",lbl="Label: ", List=myList)
        self.authorTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(140,-1))
        self.button =wx.Button(self, label="Save")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, self.button)
        ...
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        box.Add(myPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        box.Add(self.authorTxt, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        box.Add(self.button, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        ...
```

testPanel.py

```
import wx
class testPanel(wx.Panel):
    def EvtComboBox(self, event):
        print"%s was selected" % event.GetString()

    def __init__(self, parent, ID, name, lbl, List = []):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, ID)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label=lbl, size=(-1,1))
        cb = wx.ComboBox(self, size=(-1, 1), choices=List, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.EvtComboBox, cb)
        ...
```

I am trying to make the text field "authorTxt" editable and uneditable depending on which ComboBox item is selected. Is there a way to bind the ComboBox event from testPanel.py in main.py?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the following:

First, when you define cb in testPanel do it as:

```
self.cb = ...
```

Then you can do:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.EvtComboBox, myPanel.cb)
```

Where `self.EvtComboBox` would be a new function you need to define in MyFrame

That said, I highly recommend you use PubSub in this situation:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxLibPubSub

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern

EDIT: cb needed to be a member of testPanel

Comment: Thank you for your response! After adding `self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.EvtComboBox, myPanel.cb)` to MyFrame I got the following error: self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.EvtComboBox, myPanel.cb)
AttributeError: type object 'testPanel' has no attribute 'cb'

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I'll check out PubSub